# How to I set interface which id contained in normal Class(not activity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I'm using an app which contain `viewPager` and `TapLayout`. And a fragment which showed on ViewPager has `Bluetooth` connecting function. When I tab a button on a fragment, Ble Started.
But in that process, I got an

> interface ClassCastException Error

A fragment implement interface which in BluetoothController. BluetoothController need context, so I passed context(getContext) which got in Fragment.
When I implement interface and pass context in MainActivity, it works well. But I do that in fragment, Android studio occurs 'interface ClassCastException Error'.
I should implement interface in fragment, because interface pass Bluetooth state like Connecting, DisConnecting, Start etc.
How can I set interface in fragment?

When MainActivity implement interface, Bluetooth interface works well. But that case, Bluetooth state is not passed in fragment. It pass state in MainActivity. I think when I got state in MainActivity,  pass the state to fragment is one of the solution for this problem. But I think it is not good method.

here is BluetoothContoller code

```
public class BluetoothController extends BluetoothPacketController
{
    public static final String TAG = BluetoothController.class.getSimpleName() +"_Debug";

    private static Context context;

    private static final int SCAN_PERIOD = 1000*10;

    private int BLE_STATE = BLUETOOTH_STATE.IDLE;
    private BleInterface mListener;

    public class BLUETOOTH_STATE {
        public static final int IDLE = 0;
        public static final int SCANNING = 1;
        public static final int CONNECTION_TRY = 2;
        public static final int CONNECTION_ERR = 3;
        public static final int CONNECTION_SUCC = 4;
        public static final int DISCONNECTION = 5;
    }

    public interface BleInterface{
        void bleScanTimeOut();
        void bleScanStart();
        void bleScanStop();
        void bleConnectTry();
        void bleDisConnectTry();
        void bleErrDisConnectTry();
        void bleDisConnected();
        void bleResult(boolean ret);
        void bleResult(String ret);
    }

    private static BluetoothController instance = null;


    @Override
    public void setContext(Context context) {
        super.setContext(context);
        this.context = context;

    }

    public static BluetoothController getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new BluetoothController();

        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Context context) {
        super.init(context);
        setContext(context);
        mListener = (BluetoothController.BleInterface) context;//listener;//(BluetoothController.BleInterface) context;

    }
    ...
}
```

And here is fragment code

```
public class RegistrationFragment extends Fragment implements BluetoothController.BleInterface{

    private View view;
    public static final String TAG = RegistrationFragment.class.getSimpleName() + "_Debug";

    private static RegistrationFragment instance = null;

    public static RegistrationFragment getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RegistrationFragment();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_view, container, false);

        BluetoothScanUpperAPI21.getInstance().init(getContext());
        BluetoothScanUnderAPI21.getInstance().init(getContext());
        BluetoothController.getInstance().init(getContext());

        startUi_init();

        return view;
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to get Bluetooth state through BleInterface in fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you casting `context` in `BleInterface`? Can't you pass `this` from fragment to `BluetoothController` where `this` referes `BleInterface` which is implemented in fragment?

**In Fragment**

```
BluetoothController.getInstance().init(this);
```

**BleController's Init:**

```
 @Override
    public void init(BluetoothController.BleInterface ble) {
        super.init(context);
        setContext(context);
        mListener = ble;
    }
```

**Reason for the behaviour that you are facing**:
Fragment doesn't have their own context. They always refers to activity context. So, when you pass `getContext()`, it refers to activity context and compiler tries to find `BleInterface` in activity which does not exists. That's why you are facing `ClassCastException`.

Comment: I see that I face this problem. But I cann't understand 'BluetoothController.getInstance().init(this);'You said fragment has not their own context. So I cann't input 'this'. And the reason why I cast context is the app has five fragment and two of them have bluetooth function. So my listener should distinguish which fragment use bluetooth function. And I cann't understand 'BleController's init' too. But exactly understand why occurred this problem. Thx!

Comment: @youngtaek `this` will refers the interface's object that you implemented in fragment. So, in every fragment, implement interface and then pass `this` in init method. You will received seperate events in seperate fragments. It's equivalent to passing any variable to method.